# Geochart columns

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a GeoChart for my job. Basically we broke down every County in NE. So on hover we want to show differen data info per County. However, every time I try to add another set of information, I receive the message:

"Incompatible data table: Error: Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 3 columns)"

So I was wondering how to add more columns or is there another way to do this.

Basically every county will have 7 different lines of data info

I'm just adding a few counties but the plan is to use all 90+ counties in NE.

Here is the live page: www.nefb.org/tpp

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                     google.load('visualization', '1', {
                      packages: ['geochart'],
                      callback: drawVisualization
                });
                
                var list;
                function drawVisualization() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Country', 'Pork', 'Cattle'],
                    [{v: "NE-01",f: "Adams"}, 215726, 2234215], /** Adams **/
                    [{v: "NE-02",f: "Antelope"}, 2573422, 3011952], /** Antelope **/
                    [{v: "NE-03",f: "Arthur"}, 0, 0], /** Arthur **/
                    [{v: "NE-04",f: "Banner"}, 0, 1301768], /** Banner **/
                    [{v: "NE-05",f: "Blaine"}, 0, 429964], /** Blaine **/
                    [{v: "NE-06",f: "Boone"}, 3364104, 2797416], /** Boone **/
                    [{v: "NE-07",f: "Box Butte"}, 922, 1941744], /** Box Butte **/
    ]);
                      google.visualization.GeoChart.setMapsSource('http://chrisdblumberg.com/maps')
                      var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
                      document.getElementById('visualization'));
                      geochart.draw(data, {
                       height: 400,
                       region: 'US-NE',
                       resolution: 'provinces',
                       legend: 'null',
                       enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
                       colorAxis: {
                        colors: ['#F5F0E1', '#F5F0E1'], /**'#c0a940', **/
                       },
                      });
                     }
</script>
```

```html
 <script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <div id="visualization" style="max-width: 640px; width: 100%; position: absolute;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you strip out those extra trailing commas? 1. before /** Box Butte **/ 2. before comment in colors line 3. after your colorAxis declaration.  Semicolon after blumberg's map line?  And perhaps change "Country" column heading to "County" for accuracy.